# Creating a custom 2D array Tile Map with text file using line.Split gives null exception error

Tags: java, split, text-files, game-engine, multidimensional-array

I have written the following code to read a tile map from a text file, however I am getting a null point exception error for a reason I can't figure out.

Code of the reader:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));

        readMapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        readMapHeight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        map = new int[readMapHeight][readMapWidth];

        for(int row = 0; row < readMapHeight; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
            for(int col = 0; col < readMapWidth; col++){
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tileValues[col]);  

            }
        }
    }
```

The text file content:

[image]

What the command console returns as an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at TileMap.<init>(TileMap.java:58)
```

which is line:

```
                String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
```

The lines read perfectly and I can draw the map to the screen. however I need an actually stored 2d array to use for pathfinding later, but this line is returning a null value and I can't understand why.

Here is what the "System.out.println(line)" returns that confuses me:

```
[final line of the map here, map lines print as normal]
null
```

The null? I don't understand, my text file only has 27 lines where is the null exception regarding split coming from?

Comment: `27 - 2 = 25`...Your texture is actually only 25 lines high...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have reached the end of file or encountered an empty line, causing your  line String to be null here:

```
        String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
```

better you put a check for end of file or at least put a null check on line before you operate on it to split it.

```
  for(int row = 0; row < readMapHeight; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if(line == null || line.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Line is empty or null");
            } else {
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
                for(int col = 0; col < readMapWidth; col++){
                   map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tileValues[col]);  

            }
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things stand out...

1. `br.readLine()` returns `null` when it reaches the end of the file.
2. Your file only contains 25 lines of data (after the height and width lines).  Ie `27 - 2 = 25`

A better approach might be to do something like...

```
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));

    readMapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    readMapHeight = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    map = new int[readMapHeight][readMapWidth];

    int row = 0;
    String text = null;
    while ((text = br.readline()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] tileValues = line.split(",");
        for(int col = 0; col < readMapWidth; col++){
            map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tileValues[col]);  
        }
        row++;
    }

    // Zero index rows...
    if (row < readMapHeight - 1) {
        throw IOException("Expected title height does not match actual row height");
    }    
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } cacth (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

If your texture size is correct, you might be expecting a total of 27 lines, not just 27 lines for the texture, so you would need to adjust the row count accordingly

Answer (score 1):

you should replace your data file before start

```
var readed_data:String = read whole data as String;

while (readed_data.search("\r") != -1) //MAC line reset cmd
{
     readed_data = readed_data.replace("\r", ""); //replace to nullstring
{

while (readed_data.search("\r") != -1) //UNIX line reset cmd
{
     readed_data = readed_data.replace("\n", ""); //replace to nullstring
{

//And so Windows uses both of "\n" and "\r" strings in text files as a quarantee, now you can read your data as you wish... now all data is single line data and you can split with "," comma after this time easily and without unneeded characters
```